# FabricJS: Issue when changing objects coordinates inside a Group after some Transformations

Tags: fabricjs

I am looking for a way to space (and move in general) objects inside a group regardless of their transformation.
In the small example i have made below, you will see 2 circles and I am attempting to space them by a certain factor.
It is ok until I rotate or resize the group and it is still ok the very first time the coordinates are changed after a transformation but calling the same function twice while the spacing is still correct, the group starts jumping all over the places..

I am using Fabric JS version: 1.7.7

Here is a sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/u0patgck/

```
console.clear();
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('root');
var circles = [];

circles.push(new fabric.Circle({id: "circle1", radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 150, top: 100}));
circles.push(new fabric.Circle({id: "circle2", radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 200, top: 100}));

g = new fabric.Group(circles);
//once circles are added to group their coordinates change so I store their new original base coordinates in custom variables
g.forEachObject(function(obj){ 
        obj.originalLeft = obj.getLeft();
        obj.originalTop = obj.getTop();
}, g);

canvas.add(g);
canvas.renderAll();

function moveCircles(){
        var space = parseFloat(document.getElementById("spacingPixels").value);
        g.forEachObject(function(obj){ 
        switch (obj.id){
          case "circle1":
            obj.setLeft(obj.originalLeft - space)
            break;
          case "circle2":
            obj.setLeft(obj.originalLeft + space)
              break;
          default:      
        }        
    })
    g.addWithUpdate();
    canvas.renderAll()
}
```

**Steps to Reproduce**:

Test 1 (ok):
Click the "Move Circles" button as many times you want (circles coordinates are recalculated and the group is not "misbehaving".
Test 2 (ok first time but not second time):
Rotate the group first.
Click the move circles button ONE time (all is still good)
Click the move circles button another time (you will see the group starts moving by itself around the canvas).

**Expected Behaviour:**

The group should not move around or change the order of the objects inside.

The group moves erratically.

At the moment I am caching the transformations manually and restoring them after changing the coordinates (like below)

https://jsfiddle.net/0tdg1dof/

```
var a = {scaleX: g.getScaleX(), scaleY: g.getScaleY(), skewX: g.getSkewX(), skewY: g.getSkewY(), flipX: g.getFlipX(), flipY:g.getFlipX(), angle: g.getAngle()};
fabric.util.resetObjectTransform(g);      
g.addWithUpdate();
g.setScaleX(a.scaleX);
g.setScaleY(a.scaleY);
g.setSkewX(a.skewX);
g.setSkewY(a.skewY);
g.setFlipX(a.flipX);
g.setFlipY(a.flipY);
g.setAngle(a.angle);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlessandroDM, I believe you did right solution, because you are manipulating just only group object. If you will not manipulate (restore) group objects (parent) you will need to do manipulation each child inside the group like angle, scale, etc. Also, you have one minor bug, if you will rotate group, and after that resize it (not diagonal controls, scaleX should not be equal to scaleY) and then click "Move Circles" your group will behave as  you described in Test 2. In order to fix that you will need to set scaleX and scaleY values after all your values which you want to set:

```
var a = {scaleX: g.getScaleX(), scaleY: g.getScaleY(), skewX: g.getSkewX(), skewY: g.getSkewY(), flipX: g.getFlipX(), flipY:g.getFlipX(), angle: g.getAngle()};
fabric.util.resetObjectTransform(g);      
g.addWithUpdate();
g.setSkewX(a.skewX);
g.setSkewY(a.skewY);
g.setFlipX(a.flipX);
g.setFlipY(a.flipY);
g.setAngle(a.angle);
g.setScaleX(a.scaleX);
g.setScaleY(a.scaleY);
```

It is not a fabricjs bug setting scale after all manipulations, even native HTML5 canvas required scaling after all manipulations.

Comment: Thank you (also for the scaling correction). I thought that since calling g.addWithUpdate() internally calls "resetObjectTransform" I thought fabric should have taken care of this itself and that mine was a "bad" workaround..